# Reference static resource in the header of a community portal

Tags: javascript, community, header

I need to reference a static resource JS file from the header of a community portal.

What would be the appropriate way to get the url for the static resource? Right now I have the JS code of the resource loaded in the header but it's massive and I would like to move it out of the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure this syntax will work:

```
/sfsites/c/resource/resourcename/foldername
```

Your might need to experiment with the names at the end, I always get mixed up with that bit.

I use this syntax for CSS overrides in the community, so I'm fairly sure the same syntax will work for extra header markup.

Comment: Absolutely correct, thank you so much!